# Order posts by highest rated in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a site with overviews of posts which should possibly be ordered by their rating. The rating is set up in a way that people can comment on a post and submit a rating with that comment of they want. I want to create a filter that gets all the posts and shows the highest rated posts first.

The way I get the comments for a single post:

```
get_comments( array('post_id' => $post->ID) );
```

The way I get the rating from that post:

```
get_comment_meta($comment->comment_ID, 'cijfer', true );
```

Now keep in mind that not every comment will have an actual rating attached to it. How can I modify this bit of code that gets my posts to order them by rating High -> Low.

```
$order = array (
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'cat'       => $cat,
    'post_type'=> 'adressen',
    'paged'     => $paged,
);
```

Comment: check out [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) It might help you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Shah Rukh ! I can't seem to find what I'm looking for in the documentation though? :( Do you have an example maybe?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

> 'orderby' with 'meta_value' and custom post type
>
> Display posts of type 'my_custom_post_type', ordered by 'age', and filtered to show only ages 3 and 4 (using meta_query).

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'my_custom_post_type',
    'meta_key'   => 'age',
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'age',
            'value'   => array( 3, 4 ),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm afraid this won't work though. What this does is get posts and orders them by the value of an 'age' field in the actual post and only gets post with a 3 or 4 as value in that field. This is not the functionality I am looking for. Thank you for your trouble though!

Comment: try to use just key => 'cijfer'

Comment: I figured that much out ;) I'm afraid this method just doesn't work for what I want.